# JS - add multiple dict values into a dict key

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary as as shown below. I am trying to add dict values into them. **This is what it stars with**

```
var animals = {
        flying : {},
        underground : {},
        aquatic : {},
        desert : {}
    };
```

For example: If I wanted to add `d = {dove : [<some list>] }` into `animal[flying]`, how would i do it? I cannot enter the values manually as thus i am running a loop, I am able to write it manually, but not with program.

I have tried `animals[flying] = d`, this would work for the first time, but when i try to add another value it would be replaced and not appended.

In the end I am looking for something like this: **This is what it ends with**

```
var animals = {
        flying : {
            dove : [<list>],
            sparrow : [<list>],

        },
        underground : {
            rabbits : [<list>],
            squirrel : [Squirrel],

        },
        aquatic : {
            dolphin : [<list>],
            whale : [Squirrel],

        },
        desert : {
            camel : [<list>],
            antelope : [<list>],

        },
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newAnimal = {name: 'bird'};    
if(animals['flying']['dove'] && animals['flying']['dove'].length > 0) {
   //List already exists so add the new animal
   //TODO also check if the animal is already in the list?
   animals['flying']['dove'].push(newAnimal);
}else {
   //Create the new list
   animals['flying']['dove'] = [newAnimal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is:

```
animals["flying"] = Object.assign(animals["flying"], d);
```

E.g.

```
animals = {
    flying: {}
}

d = { dove: [1, 2, 3] }
Object.assign(animals["flying"], d);
d = { sparrow: [1, 2, 3] }
Object.assign(animals["flying"], d);
console.log(animals); //{"flying":{"dove":[1,2,3],"sparrow":[1,2,3]}}
```

Comment: That’s equivalent to `Object.assign(animals["flying"], d);`. `Object.assign` already mutates the first argument. Also `animals["flying"]` can be rewritten as `animals.flying`.

Answer (score 1):

well because

```
myDict[subcat] = x
```

assigns it. You're working with lists. Think about it - when have you ever added an item to a list this way? Of course that overwrites your previous entry. What you want instead is to *push* the variable into the array  (also, this isn't python. Lists are called Arrays and Dictionaries are called Objects. There is a distinction, but that's beyond the scope of an answer here. Google it).

So do this:

```
myDict = {
    subCat: [],
}
```

And then when you loop:

```
myDict[subCat].push(x)
```